# How long does Reality Enforcement last?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

The Exploit "Reality Enforcement" describes its effects, and its range, but it never describes how long it lasts.

> Success: Everyone in the immediately area (demon’s Primum x 4
>   in yards) that is in any way connected to the God-Machine — demons,
>   angels and stigmatics — feels their power and awareness drain
>   away. Angels crash the ground, materialized and solid, but unable
>   to use their Numina. Demons are unable to spend Aether or use
>   Embeds
>
> Dramatic Failure: The demon causes an influx of Aether,
>   amplifying all angelic and demonic powers well beyond the ability
>   of their wielders to control them. Any expenditure of Aether
>   or Essence sparks a coruscating wave of electricity that inflicts
>   the Primum rating or Rank of the spender in lethal damage to
>   everyone within five yards (including the character who spent the
>   Aether/Essence). The demon also gains the Flagged Condition.

I'd *assume* it's supposed to last for "one scene," and that the Dramatic Failure case should have the same duration and radius of effect (on any targets within Primum x 4 yards) as the success case. But have the devs ever clarified *officially* anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

It is safe to assume that it would last for "one scene".  As a storyteller, I use the general rule that if a power has an Instant action for activation, it likely lasts for one scene (unless stated otherwise such as  1 hour per Supernatural Rating, etc.).

Most of the time, if something last more than one scene, an extended action or something similar is required (additional fuel such as mana or Aether, etc. per hour/roll, whatever).